# compiling opencv2 fails ‘Z_RLE’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having the following issue while running cmake_make_isolated.

> ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/opencv2/modules/highgui/src/grfmt_png.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool cv::PngEncoder::write(const cv::Mat&, const std::vector&)’:
> ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/opencv2/modules/highgui/src/grfmt_png.cpp:361:44: error: ‘Z_RLE’ was not declared in this scope
> ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/opencv2/modules/highgui/src/grfmt_png.cpp:374:48: error: ‘Z_FIXED’ was not declared in this scope
> make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_png.cpp.o] Error 1
> make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
> make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
> make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

I did some searching and found that Z_RLE is associated with zlib, and I checked and found that it was installed and up to date

> Package zlib-1.2.7-9.fc18.x86_64 already installed and latest version

rosdep didn't report any missing dependencies. What do I do to resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64722/compiling-opencv2-fails-%E2%80%98z_rle%E2%80%99-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/) by [flashedarling](https://answers.ros.org/users/5110/flashedarling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer myself. I had multiple copies of libz.h on my system, one of which was older and did not have the correct definitions. By reorganizing my path I was able to get the correct libz.h file to be imported.

---

Originally posted by [flashedarling](https://answers.ros.org/users/5110/flashedarling/) with karma: 36 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0